# dummy variable based on unique column interaction

Tags: r

I have the following data and wish to create an `$ID` variable for each unique interaction between two columns

```
DATE <- c('V', 'V', 'W', 'W', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Z', 'Z')
SEX <- rep(1:2, 5)
Blood_T1 <- c(3,4,3,3,4,3,1,6,3,4)
Blood_T2 <- c(4,3,3,3,3,4,6,1,4,3)
df1 <- data.frame(DATE, SEX, Blood_T1, Blood_T2)
```

When grouping by `$DATE`, I want to create a new dummy variable for each unique combination of `$Blood_T1` and `$Blood_T2` regardless of their order.

The desired out appears below:

[image]

I cant use the sum, as it does not always produce unique combinations. (*See the part marked in yellow above for clarification*)

I have tried the following commands but have not yet hit the nail on the head

```
with(df1, interaction(Blood_T1, Blood_T2))
as.numeric(as.factor(with(df1, paste(Blood_T1, Blood_T2))))
transform(df1, Cluster_ID = as.numeric(interaction(Blood_T1, Blood_T2, drop=TRUE)))
```

Comment: `interaction` does exactly what you say you want to do. Is it _really_ what you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try with `data.table`.   Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), get the `pmin` and `pmax` of the 'Blood_T1' and 'Blood_T2' columns, `paste`, it together, `match` the values with the `unique` elements to create the 'Unique_ID', then we group by 'DATE' and concatenate the `sum` of 'Blood_T1' and 'Blood_T2' to create the 'Sum' column

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Unique_ID := {
          i1 <- paste(pmin(Blood_T1, Blood_T2), pmax(Blood_T1, Blood_T2))
           match(i1, unique(i1))}]
df1[, Sum := c(sum(Blood_T1), sum(Blood_T2)), DATE][]
#     DATE SEX Blood_T1 Blood_T2 Unique_ID Sum
#1:    V   1        3        4         1   7
#2:    V   2        4        3         1   7
#3:    W   1        3        3         2   6
#4:    W   2        3        3         2   6
#5:    X   1        4        3         1   7
#6:    X   2        3        4         1   7
#7:    Y   1        1        6         3   7
#8:    Y   2        6        1         3   7
#9:    Z   1        3        4         1   7
#10:   Z   2        4        3         1   7
```

---

The above can be also implemented in `base R` i.e. vectorized approach.

```
i1 <- with(df1, paste(pmin(Blood_T1, Blood_T2), pmax(Blood_T1, Blood_T2)))
df1$Unique_ID <- match(i1, unique(i1))
```

Comment: thank you, i guess I need to enroll into one of your course ASAP to reach your wizard knowledge.

Comment: @lukeg Thank you for the comment.  But, I think you may be referring to Arun, the `data.table` developer (which I am not)

Answer (score 2):

You can actually sort the individual pairs (`$Blood_T1` and `$Blood_T2`) and `paste` them together which is already *a kind of* ID

```
apply(df1, 1, function(x) paste(sort(x[3:4]), collapse = ""))
#[1] "34" "34" "33" "33" "34" "34" "16" "16" "34" "34"
```

If you want to further reduce it, you can treat it as a factor and obtain the numeric value

```
as.numeric(as.factor(apply(df1, 1, function(x) paste(sort(x[3:4]), collapse = ""))))
#[1] 3 3 2 2 3 3 1 1 3 3
```

You could throw in `DATE` too, if that is necessary

```
apply(df1, 1, function(x) paste(sort(x[c(1,3:4)]), collapse = ""))
#[1] "34V" "34V" "33W" "33W" "34X" "34X" "16Y" "16Y" "34Z" "34Z"
```